# App crash on 'arm64-v8a','x86_64' in react native modules

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

App crash on 'arm64-v8a','x86_64' in react native modules

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dbplc.parentapp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 42
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

But if I exclude it can't upload on the store because : "**The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 42.**"

```
packagingOptions {
            exclude '/lib/mips64/**'
            exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/**'
            exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which version of RN that you are running, so I'll assume that you mean this bug found here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24261

I have experienced app crashing on a Samsung 7 Edge from that bug.
However, some time later a patch was created and added to RN 0.59.10.

`Upgrading to at least RN 0.59.10 should fix that crash on the 64 bit apks.`